# How to use Data.Data?

Tags: haskell, scrap-your-boilerplate, rank-n-types

As I'm not familiar with rank-N types, the type signature of `gfoldl` is a troublesome for me:

```
gfoldl :: (forall d b. Data d => c (d -> b) -> d -> c b)
-> (forall g. g -> c g)
-> a
-> c a
```

The only functions I can think of are `\xs y -> ($y) <$> xs` and `pure`, respectively.

Other functions such as `gunfold` and `gmapT` have similar problems. So what are notable examples of nontrivial uses of them?

Comment: There should be a SYB (scrap your boilerplate) tutorial in the 'net. Even more than one. I'd start there, since the relatively low-level primitives like `gfoldl` are very general and hardish to understand at first. Also, SYB is probably not the easiest way to learn rank-N types.

Comment: Also, SYB is a lot harder to grasp than GHC.Generics (though arguably more elegant), so if you want this for automating instance-generation then you may be better off with Generic.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I guess `gfoldl` has some functionalities that GHC.Generics can't cover.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's more elegant; it's just different. `Data.Data` has an "untyped" feel and is "deep", while `GHC.Generics` has a very "typed" feel (though less than `generics-sop`) and is "shallow". My general impression is that `Data.Data` is mostly about offering tools to make AST manipulation convenient, while `GHC.Generics` is more about class defaults and the like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `gmapT` case the `mkT` function is defined for this purpose in the original paper.

```
mkT :: (Typeable a, Typeable b ) => (b -> b) -> a -> a
mkT f = fromMaybe id (cast f)
```

For example to increment all `int` fields in the `A`, you can write something like

```
data A = A {f :: Int, s :: Int} deriving (Data, Typeable)

ex = gmapT (mkT inc) (A 2 3) where 
  inc :: Int -> Int
  inc = (+1)
```

To make it clearer the `ex` function can be written like this too:

```
ex2 = gmapT f (A 2 3) where 
  f :: (Data a ) =>  a -> a
  f a = case cast a of 
    Nothing -> a
    (Just (b :: Int)) -> fromJust $ cast (b + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Data.Data` is part of a generic metaprogramming framework called "Scrap your boilerplate".

- The `Data.Data` module links to a list of research publications on the topic https://wiki.haskell.org/Research_papers/Generics#Scrap_your_boilerplate.21
- The [syb library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb-0.7.1) is full of examples of generic transformations, see in particular the [Schemes module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb-0.7.1/docs/Data-Generics-Schemes.html)
- There used to be a SYB wiki (linked from `Data.Data` and syb) but sadly it seems dead now.
- For a different kind of example, [boltzmann-samplers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/boltzmann-samplers) (I'm the author) uses `Data.Data` for generic random generators with some uniformity properties.